# How to download files on client side from physical path in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have a generic controller which I call using AJAX. It recieves the path from a file

`(for example: C:\\Control_Ventas\\2022\\2022_03\\13032022\\58_13032022\\hola.txt)`

In this case is a txt but it could be a pdf or a excel document. I tried to make it work with this code, but it didnt worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Dbventas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción breve de FileDownloadHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class FileDownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            string filePath = context.Request.Form.Get("path");
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.Buffer = true;
            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@filePath);
            response.BinaryWrite(data);
            response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
this is de AJAX call and the code that I modified. Now the file is sent to the client, but i dont know how to build the file again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Dbventas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción breve de FileDownloadHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class FileDownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
         
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            string filePath = context.Request.Form.Get("path");
            filePath = filePath.Replace("/", @"\");
            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@filePath);
            response.Clear();
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=FILENAME");
            response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AJAX call

```
function downloadFile(id) {
        
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("nombre", document.getElementById(id).dataset.filename);
        fd.append("path", document.getElementById(id).dataset.path);
        console.log(fd);
        
        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'FileDownloadHandler.ashx',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
                processData: false, // Not to process data  
                data: fd,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
        } catch (exception) {
            console.log("ERROR"); alert(exception);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What "didn't work" about it?  How specifically does this code fail?

Comment: It doesnt work. This code triggers when i click a button, but it doesnt download the file. Doesn´t give any error.

Comment: Then what *does* it do?  When you debug, is this code invoked at all?  Stepping through the code in a debugger, does it complete as expected?  Is any error produced?  In the browser's debugging tools, what is the request made to the server?  What is the server's response?  We need specific information about the problem, not just "it doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry, this is my second post here. When i debug it the code is invoked at all, and there´s no error, but the function System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@filePath) doesn´t return anything. The request made to the server is correct, it only sends one param which is path, and the server recieves it fine.

Comment: Edit: I found that the path was written with a bad format and now it reads the file, but still doesnt download.

Comment: Please post the HTML form where you are collecting the path. It is not clear if this path is a server path or a client path.

Comment: @pedromartinez: So debugging now confirms that `data` successfully contains all of the bytes for the file?  Is it successfully written to the output?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the response from the server?  Does it contain the file data?

Comment: Yes, i managed to send it to client side modifying the code. Ill paste it

Answer (score 0):

I've had a case like this, but in vb.net

I'm change :

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=FILENAME");
            response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

To:

```
Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Pck.GetAsByteArray())
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Filename.xlsx")
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray())
            Response.End()
```

maybe you can search code similar like above in c#